# Junit code coverage not displayed on SonarQube 5.4

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are using Jenkins as the CI tool to integrate sonar and other build tools (maven). We were using Jenkins version of 1.547 with SonarQube 3.7.4. We were able to view the JUnit coverage on sonar earlier. We have upgraded Jenkins to 1.656 and sonarqube to 5.4. After the upgrade, it always displays:

> This component does not have coverage details.

I understand, execution of unit test is stopped from the sonar version above 4.2. But a maven goal "org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true" has been added to run the unit tests explicitly. This shows the tests being executed successfully on Jenkins job console. But on coverage tab of sonar, nothing is displayed.

What could be the issue? Any missing sonar configuration or Jenkins plugin is required for the same ?

Comment: I would start by double checking in the Jenkins workspace that the jacoco report is really generated. Then if this is the case, I would double check the value of the "sonar.jacoco.reportPath" property. And finally if everything is well configured, I would have a look to the SonarQube analysis log file.

Comment: @Freddy - SonarSource Team 
But I checked with the Jenkins workspace and sonar configurations. I have added the below properties  in sonar.conf file. I can see the surefire reports in the folder location. 

    sonar.binaries=build/classes
    sonar.tests=junit
    sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
    sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/jacoco.exec

When the job is executed on Jenkins, it displays 
[INFO] JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : <folders...>/target/jacoco.exe
[INFO] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: <folders...>/target/jacoco-it.exec

Comment: I checked for the 2 jacoco files, i was able to see them physically at the required locations. 

what else could be the issue ?

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Comment: I'm sorry but the message is clear : JaCoCo report not found : <folders...>/target/jacoco.exe. Are you sure the SonarQube analysis is launched AFTER the build and unit test execution ?